# is pattern validation deprecated in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: java, annotations, openapi, deprecated

I would like to know if the pattern validation is deprecated in OpenAPI 3, because my colleague replaced this code:

```
@Operation(summary = "Returns MyObject", description = "Returns MyObject", operationId = "getMyObject")
@ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ok"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Not authorized!"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Forbidden!"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not found!") })
public MyObject getMyObject(
        @PathVariable @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\d\\w]{8}-[\\d\\w]{4}", message = "Unknown Pattern") String id)
```

with this one, hence erasing the `Pattern` annotation:

```
@Operation(summary = "Returns MyObject", description = "Returns MyObject", operationId = "getMyObject")
@ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ok"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Not authorized!"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Forbidden!"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not found!") })       
public MyObject getMyObject(
        @PathVariable String id)
```

Comment: Wouldn't checking the OpenAPI 3.0 documentation answer your question? Also, shouldn't your first move be to ask your colleague why they changed this?

Comment: Hi, on swagger.io website in 3.0 specification I don't see anything about deprecation of Pattern annotation, even if a search on internet. My colleague replacement on our git repository was motiveted by deprecation of Pattern annotation.